# XML and SelectNodes

Tags: c#, xml

A pretty newbie question as I rarely work with XML.  I'm trying out writing stuff for the Subsonic API.  The xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.6.0">
  <indexes lastModified="1313158157783">
    <index name="A">
      <artist name="Albums" id="5c5c3139322e3136382e322e31305c566f6c756d655f315c4d757369635c416c62756d73"/>
    </index>
    <index name="S">
      <artist name="Singles" id="5c5c3139322e3136382e322e31305c566f6c756d655f315c4d757369635c53696e676c6573"/>
    </index>
  </indexes>

</subsonic-response>
```

I'm just trying to get the index nodes.

I'm trying this, but not sure if I am doing this right.  Both the SelectNodes and SelectSingleNode are returning emtpy.  I'm sure I am missing something simple.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(index.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://subsonic.org/restapi");

XmlNodeList xnList = index.SelectNodes("/subsonic-response/indexes/index", nsmgr);
XmlNode mainnode = index.SelectSingleNode("/subsonic-response", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
}
```

I've tried with and without the namespacemanager and it's the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a non-empty XML namespace prefix:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(index.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://subsonic.org/restapi");

XmlNodeList xnList = index.SelectNodes("/x:subsonic-response/x:indexes/x:index", nsmgr);
XmlNode mainnode = index.SelectSingleNode("/x:subsonic-response", nsmgr);
```

I've had trouble with trying to use the empty string as a (default) XML namespace prefix

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://subsonic.org/restapi");
```

And:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = index.SelectNodes("/x:subsonic-response/x:indexes/x:index", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you and marc had the same answer, wish I could do double "answered"